# Compilation error in bootstrap less file

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

While compiling  grid.less in bootstrap package i got the following error.

```
> NameError: .make-grid-columns is undefined in grid.less:48:0
```

48 .make-grid-columns();

Comment: Do you have edited the boostrap source code? If not why don't you just download the compiled version? If yes show us the relevant modified parts.

Comment: no i do not modify any code 
https://github.com/pinax/pinax-theme-bootstrap/blob/master/pinax_theme_bootstrap/static/bootstrap/less/grid.less
the file is same as in the link. i need no customize a theme for that i am in need to compile default less and my customized less into single file

Comment: That's simply because the `.make-grid-columns` mixin indeed is not defined in "grid.less" (it's in "mixins.less" actually). I.e., in general, Bootstrap less files are not supposed to be compiled/imported separately but only all together via the master "bootstrap.less" (though you can get "grid.less" working alone by additionally importing "variable.less" and "mixins.less").

Comment: i imported all the required files still it shows the same error msg

Comment: How do you compile that? It still looks like you're trying to compile either all files in the bs directory or something like that ("grid.less" should find `.make-grid-columns` if "mixins.less" is imported before or after).

Comment: yes i compile all the files in bs and i also imported the mixins.less file

Comment: You should compile *only* bootstrap.less or your own less file (where you included those bs files in). Yet again: most of less files in the BS dir are not supposed to be compiled on their own.

Answer (score 2):

guys i found the solution, simply upgrade the LESS compiler to 1.6.3 then it compile all the files. finally i got my own theme